# Private classes and uml

Tags: java, uml

I have some inner private classes and I am unsure where to put them in my class diagrams.
Should they be in their external classes or on their own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UML is for designing or describing complex architectures. I don't think an inner class is that important to mention it in an UML class diagram. If you design your system on the interface level your implementation and so the private class is out of focus, as well as all private methods. Your diagrams should only contain public methods = interface methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can represent them externally with a `containment` having a `+` sign on the side of the outer class. You can find it [here](http://www.holub.com/goodies/uml/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

There's always a difference between UML the language and whatever modelling tool you're using, so which is the best way of achieving something depends on the tool.

In UML, classes have a visibility/scope, just like class members do. In other words, UML allows for private classes, but that doesn't mean your tool can display the "privateness" of the class.

UML also allows classes to contain other classes. I other words, classes can act as packages. Again, how the tool displays this varies.

From a pure UML perspective, I would recommend having the inner class contained inside the outer, and marked private.

In a diagram, if your tool doesn't show the namespace, you could resize the outer class and place the inner inside it. If your tool allows resizing, that is.

Finally, unless you only have eight or ten classes in total, I would recommend showing the inner classes in a separate diagram.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have a class inside another class in a UML class diagram. The way you present them in UML should reflect their structural relation to the parent classes. If they are created inner just for convenience you could just connect them. If they have containment or aggregation relationships, UML has the appropriate syntax. In any case, inner classes are language-specific and so it would be strange (and indeed an erroneous design) for UML to have any explicit support for them.

Potentially related external discussion: http://www.coderanch.com/t/99318/patterns/Inner-Class-UML

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I found[image]

Source http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=336264&seqNum=3